# How do you correct a line in psql without retyping everything

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am very new to databases and their software. I was just typing and made a small mistake ( forgot a ,). Now I have been searching for a way to correct the line without having to abort and retype the whole thing. Can anyone help?

Comment: try to be more descriptive and add some code to your question to make it easier to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The details of how this works depends on the line-editing library that is linked with your `psql`: readline, libedit or (on Windows) none. I assume readline with emacs-style behavior.

If you are still in the same line, you can move the cursor back and fix it. You can skip words backwards with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. To move back to the end of the line, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

If you made the mistake further up in a multi-line statement, enter `\e` and type <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start your default editor (configurable with the environment variable `EDITOR`) with the whole statement so far in it.